# How to set osmdroid source using XYTileSource

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid

Now i have a code which im using osmdroid to display my own offline maps which are placed in /osmdroid
the other special thing im trying to change is the min and max zoom
,now im using this part of code which is displaying nothing

```
MapView mapview = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapview.setUseDataConnection(false); 
final ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource("maps", ResourceProxy.string.mapnik, 18, 21, 256, ".png",
        "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/");

mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mapview.setTileSource(tileSource);
```

however when i set

```
setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK)
```

my offline maps work normally, but with limits on zooming

is there anything wrong in my XYTileSource?

thanks in advance

Comment: What format are the tiles you have placed in /osmdroid (and I'm assuming it was actually /sdcard/osmdroid/tiles?) Were they in a zip? pngs? jpgs? Were they in a folder called "maps" (to match your first argument to the XYTileSource)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my working code for xytilesource in osmdroid. Hope it might be helpful to someone.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapView.getController().setZoom(5);
        GeoPoint point = new LatLonPoint(6.83917,79.91455);
        //mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(51500000, 5400000));
        mapView.getController().setCenter(point);
        final MapTileProviderBasic tileProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(getApplicationContext());
        final ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource("SomeName", null, 3,14, 256, ".png",
                        "http://192.168.1.5/mapcache/tms/1.0.0/ms-base@GoogleMapsCompatible/");
        //mapView.setTileSource((new XYTileSource("localMapnik", Resource, 0, 18, 256, ".png", 
            //  "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/"))); 
        tileProvider.setTileSource(tileSource);
        final TilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(tileProvider, this.getBaseContext());
        mapView.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private static final class LatLonPoint extends GeoPoint {
        public LatLonPoint(double latitude, double longitude) {
            super((int) (latitude * 1E6), (int) (longitude * 1E6));
        }
    }
```

Layout file should include

```
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the max zoom level to whatever is appropriate for your tile source:

```
mapView.setMaxZoomLevel(18);
```